# How to debug AspNet 5 app on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Im playing with the new `Visual Studio Code` on `Windows 8.1` and create a new project template with the `yo` and i could see it running on my browser, but im not able to debug it, i set a break point in some action and it doesnt hit. On the debug option of `vsCode` it asks for attach a debug, but i cant find how to do it. 
At the `VsCode` website theres a paragraph saying:
`Debugging
Visual Studio Code and ASP.NET 5 are in preview and at this time debugging is not supported on OS X and Linux. Rest assured, we are working hard to bring these experiences to you in the near future.`

Is there something that im missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio Code Preview does not support ASP.Net 5 debugging now. It only supports debugging Mono applications.

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/FAQ#_debugging